# How to insert data in mongodb in .net core2.1

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to insert data in mongodb by using BsonDocument. it inserting the data like following .

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bf3eae0118cd3f6140aee72"),
    "_t" : "MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument, MongoDB.Bson",
    "_v" : {
        "_t" : "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject, Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed",
        "_v" : {
            "Email" : {
                "_t" : "JValue",
                "_v" : []
            },
            "Password" : {
                "_t" : "JValue",
                "_v" : []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The bellow code is i am using

```
public void Post([FromBody] Object value)
{   
    var document = new BsonDocument ();
    document.AddRange(value.ToBsonDocument());
     _database.GetCollection<dynamic>("Registeration").InsertOneAsync(document);
     //Console.WriteLine("Success") ;
}
```

In this i am using .net core api without model class.How can i insert the data in correct way. Please any one try to help me.

Thank you...

Comment: That's not how data is meant to be stored. That looks like the serialization of a complex object rather than "raw data". Where is `value` actually coming from when fed into the function? The malformed fields would indicate that you are attempting to parse JSON.  So your question really should be ***"How to marshal JSON into a BsonDocument"***. That's a clear title. Basically you need to show how you are reading the JSON as well. That's the real problem.

Comment: Also, please don't post screenshots. You can switch your GUI to a view which shows the "text" representation of the object structure, or simply use the `mongo` shell as I would recommend for questions posted here. Pictures just don't translate well and was in fact totally missed by the first few people viewing your post.

Comment: I am using postman to send the value

Comment: We need your code that is reading the JSON. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) at it's not about the "insert" but rather the way you are retrieving the data before this code currently in the question ever gets called. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53391519/edit) with details as outlined there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am changing bellow code

```
  var document = new BsonDocument ();
  document.AddRange(value.ToBsonDocument());
  _database.GetCollection<dynamic>("Registeration").InsertOneAsync(document);
```

to

```
 var obj = BsonDocument.Parse(value.ToString());
 _database.GetCollection<dynamic>("Registeration").InsertOne(obj);
```

OutPut:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5bf3f54b118cd3f6140aefe4"),
    "_t" : "MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument, MongoDB.Bson",
    "_v" : {
        "Email" : "test",
        "Password" : "test"
    }
```